# Problems with returning data from simple function to UI-router resolve

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-promise

I have tried all the methods I can find that suggest returning a promise object to the resolve, so that my function will process asynchronously, but still I cannot get the correct data returned - please advise :

```
        .state("app.deals.private", {
            url: "/private/",
            resolve: {
                dealsFeatured: function(Deals, $rootScope) {
                    return Deals.getDeals('FEATURED', function(data) {
                        // console.log('deals featured', data); // DATA IS HERE
                        $rootScope.loading = false;
                        return data; 
                    });
                },
                dealsGeneral: function(Deals, $rootScope, dealsFeatured) {
                    return Deals.getDeals('GENERAL', function(data) {
                        // console.log('deals general', data);  // DATA IS HERE
                        $rootScope.loading = false;
                        return data; 
                    });
                },
                dealsCats: function(Deals, dealsFeatured, dealsGeneral, $q) {

                    // ALL DEPENDENCIES HAVE DATA HERE 

                    // build a promise object
                    var deferred = $q.defer();

                    Deals.mergeCats(dealsFeatured, dealsGeneral, $q, function(data){
                        console.log("received dealsCats: " + data); 
                        //BUT....NOTHING IS RETURNED HERE, WHY NOT?!?!?!?

                        deferred.resolve(data);
                    });

                    //return the promise object
                    return deferred.promise;

                },
```

And here is the code in my service (note that the data is correct and output to console right before my callback:

```
 api.service('Deals', function(){

    this.mergeCats = function(dealsFeatured, dealsGeneral, $q, callback){

    // make one big array
    var allCats = [];
    if(Array.isArray(dealsFeatured.data.discountTermsWithCounters.cats)){
        allCats = dealsFeatured.data.discountTermsWithCounters.cats;
    }
    if(Array.isArray(dealsGeneral.data.discountTermsWithCounters.cats)){
        allCats = allCats.concat(dealsGeneral.data.discountTermsWithCounters.cats);
    }

    // now recreate the array into something we can work with
    var newCats = [];
    angular.forEach(allCats, function(value, key){
        if(newCats[value.title]){
            newCats[value.title].count += value.count;
        } else {
            newCats[value.title] = value;
        }
    });
    // after all is completed, return data to the promise object
    $q.all(allCats).then(function () {
        console.log('newCats',newCats);  // CORRECT DATA IS OUTPUTTED HERE
            // newCats data looks like this in console:
            // Array: [Herbs & Homeopathic: Object, Frozen: Object, Groceries: Object, Body Care: Object, General Merchandise: Object…]
        callback(newCats);
    });

};
});
```

Please advise, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some confusion with `dealsCats` and `Deals.mergeCats` and how and why to use and pass in `$q` as a parameter.

`mergeCats` does `$q.all` which returns a promise, but `mergeCats` only ever does synchronous operations. There is no need for `$q`, promises or callbacks:

So, change `Deals.mergeCats` to the following:

```
this.mergeCats = function(dealsFeatured, dealsGeneral){
  // some other code here that creates allCats
  return allCats;
}
```

For the same reason, you don't need `$q.defer` for `dealsCats`:

```
resolve: {
    //...,
    dealsCats: function(Deals, dealsFeatured, dealsGeneral){
       return Deals.mergeCats(dealsFeatured, dealsGeneral);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried that originally, and it didn't work, which is why I thought it needed a promise object to be returned. I will try again, as you say, and let you know if it works.

Comment: OK, I've confirmed that the data is indeed being passed through to the controller,  the problem I was having was in the format of the array - Angular-ui-router would not pass an associative array with objects as values to the template, so I converted it to an object, and now it works perfectly.  Thank you for your help in steering me toward the *real* problem!